# Import Password -credential

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to send a file to email.
I found this code and it worked
but I want to add the password automatically
is there any solution ??

---

```
$MyEmail = "tests21@gmail.com"
$Password = "TEST2132"
$SMTP= "smtp.gmail.com"
$To = "TEST212@gmail.com"
$Subject = "LOG FILE!"
$Creds = (Get-Credential -Credential "$MyEmail") 
$attachment = "C:\TEST.txt" 
Start-Sleep 2

Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $MyEmail -Subject $Subject -Attachment $attachment -SmtpServer $SMTP -Credential $Creds -UseSsl -Port 587 -DeliveryNotificationOption never
```

---

[image: Prompt]

Comment: it is generally a VERY bad idea to store passwords in a script. you may be able to use `Export-CliXml` to save your encrypted credentials ... and `Import-CliXml` to load that back into your script. the encryption is per-user-&-computer ... so you will need to create the creds and save them with the account that will use them _on the system where the creds were saved_.

Comment: Adding to Lee_Dailey's comment, if this is a scheduled task running on a domain joined server you might want to invest some time researching gMSA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Non-secure method

Here is how you create a credential object from a password string.

```
# Some email credentials
$username = 'Username'
$password = 'Password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = [PSCredential]::New($username,$password)
```

As it was pointed in the comments, setting a password directly in the script is insecure since anybody that could get access to the script would see the password.

### **Secret management module method**

This method requires a little bit of preparation but is the best in my opinion since the password is retrieved from a secret vault instead of being readily available in your script.

#### Prerequisites

##### Modules

Install the following modules

```
Install-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement
Install-Module SecretManagement.JustinGrote.CredMan
```

##### Vault

Create a vault to store the email credentials and possibly many others in the future.

```
Register-SecretVault -ModuleName SecretManagement.JustinGrote.CredMan -Name 'Default'
```

##### Save the credentials into the vault.

```
$username = 'Username'
$password = 'Password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = [PSCredential]::New($username, $password)
Set-Secret -Name 'SomeEmailCreds' -Secret $Creds -Vault Default
```

#### How to use

Once every prerequisites is filled, you can get the credentials from the local vault by using the `Get-Secret` statement. The `Set-Secret` should be nowhere in your script and you should use it only if you need to update your credentials at some point.

```
$Creds = Get-Secret -Vault Default -Name 'SomeEmailCreds'
```

##### Notes

Note that the vault is "per user"  and "per machine" so it should be created on the user and the machine it will run from.

`SecretManagement` also have other modules than the CredsMan one by Justin Grote which use all sort of different vault so there are implementation for Azure key vaults, 1password, etc